# Revolution Slider with YouTube video Embedded, Video Mute Delayed

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, revolution-slider

I have this embedded into an Avada WordPress theme and I have selected all of the proper options. I have Auto Play on and the video is muted, but when the page loads you can hear a split second of sound from the video. Any ideas how to turn this off?

Thanks!